# I have installed Oracle Developer Day on OS X. Why is there a need to add new connection?

Tags: sql, oracle, macos, oracle-sqldeveloper

So, I'm trying to learn SQL. I started the labs(in Developer Day) which asked me to add a new connection. My question, to be specific, is Why to make a new connection when you already have a 'System' connection, with 'oracle' as password.

And, is there any 'bible' for SQL where dummies like me can start from scratch and learn SQL from Basics to pro level?

Answer (score 1):

Because SQL Developer is just your client, and ONLY the client.

You need a database.

SYSTEM is a default username for an Oracle Database. The database, by default listens on port '1521' for connections. And our default database name is 'XE' - that's why you see those defaults when creating a connection.

You have a couple of Oracle provided methods for starting out with our database that I recommend.

Zero setup, full browser interface, [LiveSQL](http://www.thatjeffsmith.com/archive/2016/03/a-place-to-learn-oracle-no-setup-required/).

[image]

Very little setup, full database 'in a box' [virtual machine](http://www.thatjeffsmith.com/archive/2014/02/introducing-the-otn-developer-day-database-12c-virtualbox-image/).

[image]

Both are free.

> > I started the labs(in Developer Day)
> >     It sounds like you ALREADY have the VirtualBox image. If that's true, you only need to add a connection. All of the passwords are 'oracle' - you could login as username: system, password: oracle, service name: orcl, port#: 1521.

The blog post I shared above goes into detail on how to get started on this VBox image.

Comment: That's great for people who are familiar with atleast some sql. 

Can you recommend any book which I can use like a bible and refer, to learn sql?

Comment: if you want to learn SQL from scratch, consider a book like SQL in a Nutshell from Kevin Kline. You'll just need a db somewhere to practice what you're learning.